# How best to debug logger.info(...) , logger.error(...) not writing?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

In a large project we have something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

class Test {
   static final Log logger  = LogFactory.getLog(Test.class);

   public void execute() {
      log.info("writing some info"); 
      log.error("writing some error"); 
   }
}
```

I know that as it runs: 
I am using 
 class `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger`

Because I am able to connect remotely and put a breakpoint on my debug and see what class it is.

how can I figure out what log configuration is using ?
where is it picked up from ? 
how is it configured ?

*p.s.
Note the app. is actually quite complex and it's running within web logic app server. I don't have access to all its java code.*

*p.s.II
My idea would be to inject some code inside the execute method to determine where the heck log4j.properties is , if it is there at all and so on...*

Comment: Please define the property file. i.e. `log4j.properties`

Comment: @Bhavik as far as I know it might already be there defined. I want to go and figure out where it is (if it is there)

Comment: You have to manualy configure the log4j.properties file

Comment: @Bhavik please, please read my question more carefully. I don't know whether log4j.properties is defined, if it is where it is picked up, so you can tell me to manually configure it

Comment: @Zo72 most probably you can find the log4j.properties file by default inside the WEB-INF folder just beside the classes folder in your webapp

Comment: @tito thanks for that. let's say it's there... how do I know it's the one that gets picked up

Comment: start the program/server with -Dlog4jdebug=true this will tell you on startup where the file is.

Comment: @tito by the way there is no log4j.properties under WEB-INF

Comment: @oers Thanks for that, but the app is launched via a complex script which I can't touch. All I can do, is to connect via the remote debugger.

Comment: In the classpath you may find the path of the log4j.properties file

Comment: @bhavik you mean check every jar in the classpath to see if they have log4j.properties in it ???

Comment: @Zo72 I mean in class path check the directory location where the log4j.properties file may be there.

Comment: @Bhavik the classpath has only jars something like this -classpath a.jar;b.jar;c.jar